# Similarity function in Ruby on Rails

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, fuzzy-search

For example I have a string `VOLVO EW 160 C NEUER MOTOR / NEW ENG`. Where `VOLVO` - is a brand, and `EW 160` is a model.

And I have a two tables with **Brands** and **Models**.
Models table, for example, delimited by comma `,`: EW, E, W, S, C, Z, 10, 16, 1.6, 10, 150, 160, EW160, EW 160.

How i can detect which is the model? Searched some documentation about [same function in PostgreSQL](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/pgtrgm.html).

**RoR have some Similarity function, or what is the best way to detect similar strings?**

**What is the more flexible/productive way? (PostgreSQL or RoR)**

**UPD:**
Other string example: `VOLVO EW-160 1999, 9000 operating hours`. Where the model is `EW-160`, but in database i have not this model, but have similar models `EW160` or `EW 160`

Answer (score 0):

assuming the best match is the longest one that is included in string:

```
string = 'VOLVO EW 160 C NEUER MOTOR / NEW ENG'
models = ['EW', 'E', 'W', 'S', 'C', 'Z', '10', '16', '1.6', '10', '150', '160', 'EW160', 'EW 160']

matching_models = models.select{ |m| string.include? m }

best_match = matching_models.max_by(&:length)
```

Comment: Sorry, but some strings has wrong model name, for example `EW160`, `EW-160`, `EW/160`, `EW  160` - this models are identical and most similar to `EW160` or  `EW  160`, which are exist in database.